# How to get around MAX_PATH in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, max-path

I want to be able to create files and folders inside of `LocalCacheFolder` without worrying that the total path length will be over 248 characters, which is currently a problem in my app. What is a good way to deal with this, besides making my app generate shorter paths and avoiding nesting?

**Additional context:**

I've found that WinRT apps are susceptible to MAX_PATH limitations. In my app, when calling [`StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfileasync) I get a [`System.IO.PathTooLongException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception) with the message:

> "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters."

This happens quite often when creating a few nested subfolders inside of [`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.storage.applicationdata.localcachefolder), because the LocalCacheFolder is actually `C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\<my_package>\LocalCache\`, and thus, the number of characters allowed in my own app-created folder/files is greatly reduced.

**What I have tried:**

Given the background in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247), I attempted the following to see if I could trick WinRT into using a Win32 file namespace, which would theoretically give me Unicode paths with a max length of 32,767 characters:

```
var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path;
var cacheFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\?\" + p);
```

This attempt fails with an exception: `The specified path is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700A1)`. So now I am out of ideas.

Comment: Perhaps you could try [CreateFile2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

.NET doesn't support the \?\ file paths. You'll need to rely on short file names.

It sucks, but there a MSKB on the topic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982

Comment: This isn't a .NET question per se, as I'm using WinRT APIs, not .NET APIs. Also that documentation is ancient and I question that it provides the appropriate solution here.

Comment: You definitely don't want to depend on short file names, because they might be turned off.

Comment: @FactorMystic your example is using .NET and that's why the \\?\ fails. Use native entry points for success. The documentation may be old, but it still applies.

Comment: @HarryJohnston short names aren't going anywhere for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @focuspark are you saying that if I was using WinJS to call the WinRT API, the `\\?\c:\etc\etc` would give me working StorageFolder without a 260/248 char cap?

Comment: @FactorMystic I'm saying if you use C++, you can use the Foo2 entry points which at least support the \\?\really\long\path values.

Comment: @focuspark: short names can be disabled by the system administrator either globally or on a per-volume basis.  The `fsutil behavior` command is one way to query or set this, using the `Disable8dot3` option.

Comment: The documentation for CreateFile2 doesn't mention a path length limit, which makes me think it might not have one, though that might just be an oversight in the documentation.  I don't know that you'd need to write in C++, can't you use P/Invoke from a C# Windows Store application?

Comment: Note that it might not be possible to use `\\?\c:\` paths from a Windows Store application, because Windows Runtime has to verify that the paths are to folders that the app is allowed to use, and it might not know how to parse them.